# Trying to parse xml with duplicate attribute names

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I have xml formatted like this:

```
<attribute>
    <attributeId>11111</attributeId>
    <attributeNote label="Attribute ID">ATTRIBUTE_ID</attributeNote>
    <attributeNote label="Attribute Type">Attribute type</attributeNote>
</attribute>
```

I was trying to parse it the same way I would get the id, however I'm getting a null pointer exception.

```
File inputFile = new File("C:\\docs\\xml.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
System.out.println("Root element :" + 
doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("attribute");
Node nNode = nList.item(0);
Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
eElement.getElementsByTagName("attributeNote").item(0).getTextContent();
```

last line of code is returning an NPE

Comment: Can you explain more this part: `it's not working`?

Comment: The question headline asks about duplicate *attribute* names, but from a generic XML perspective, isn't the question really about duplicate *element* names?

Comment: @JohnBollinger oh I guess so, my bad I don't work with xml that much, but yes it's the element that's duplicated.

Comment: @jhamon I am getting a nullpointer exception

Comment: You're getting an NPE *where*?  We need more information to help you sort this out: a [mre].  What you've presented already is a good start, but it's not enough to reproduce your problem, nor, if we do observe an exception, to be confident that it reflects the same issue that you're seeing.

Comment: Include the full stack trace of the exception in your question.  That stack trace will tell you, and us, what went wrong and where.

Comment: @JohnBollinger the stacktrace is just one line of NPE pointing to last line of code

    eElement.getElementsByTagName("attributeNote").item(0).getTextContent();

Comment: Do, please, edit that into the question.

Comment: updated it now!

Comment: Just realized my mistake... I thought that element was always there, but that's not the case, so I needed to surround it with null check

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code. The last line is

```
Element.getElementsByTagName("attributeNote").item(0).getTextContent();
```

This should be

```
eElement.getElementsByTagName("attributeNote").item(0).getTextContent();
```

Comment: I actually had a typo, it's eElement

Comment: @Spider Please post the stack trace as well. I get no error.

Comment: There isn't much to the stacktrace, just says npe at the last line (the line we're currently talking about)

Comment: Just figured it out... I just need a null check, because sometimes that element isn't there